# Is there a way in MIPS to read input from a user that can be either an integer or a character?

Tags: type-conversion, mips

I am writing a program in MIPS to convert a temperature in Celsius input by the user to Fahrenheit. The program loops to allow the user to do as many conversions as they want. To exit the program they are supposed to enter `q`. Is there a way to take input that can be either an integer or a character? One possible solution I thought of is reading a string and converting it to an int, but I am a bit unsure how to go about doing that. Is there a simple way of doing that conversion?

Comment: There's no way to tell the system you're interested in input that is either characters or else numbers directly but not as characters.  You just tell it you want characters, and do the rest yourself.  Simple is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 0):

```
.globl main

.data
prompt: .asciiz "Please input a Celsius temperature: "
num: .word 32
li $t4, 0



.text
main:

li $v0, 4 
la $a0, prompt  # prints Prompt
syscall     

li $v0, 5   # user input
syscall 

move $a0, $v0   # moves input value in $a0  
lw $s0, num # Loads 32 in $s0

li $t0, 0   # Sets up 9/5
li $t1, 0

mtc1 $t0, $f2   # Converts into float point numbers
mtc1 $t1, $f30


move $a1, $t3       

move $a2, $s0   
jal Temp # jumps to function Temp 

move $s4, $v0
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s4
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall



Temp:
mul $t0, $a0, 9 # 9 * userInput Should equal 180
div $t4, $t0, 5 # value of register in t0 divided by 5

add $t1, $t4, $a2   # Answer above + 32

move $v0, $t1       # places in return register
jr $ra      # Jumps to line after function call
```

I have provided an example program that only takes the temperature input in Celsius from the user and converts it into Fahrenheit. Your idea can be implemented using while loop.
for example:

```
la $t0,str #str can be the string char "q"
loop: lb $a0,0($t0)
beq $a0,$0,exit 
 # your main code
addi $t0,$t0,1
j loop
exit:
```

however it isnt easy but doable task.